# Volume enhancement of recorded calls

Tags: audio-recording, recording, sound, volume

Audio clip of recorded calls of other side is too low that cannot be heard, means two voices in audio clip are there in which one volume is very high and other is too low.

pl. guide me detail that by which method i can increase or decrease volume of separate voice.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a compressor.  It will work as long as both voices aren't speaking simultaneously.  Basically what a compressor does is that you set a threshold level and then once anything passes that threshold level, you set a ratio of how much louder you want things to get.  So for example, if you set a 2:1 ratio, then everything louder than the threshold would only get half as much louder as it otherwise would.

If you set to ratio to infinity, it becomes a limiter as nothing can exceed the threshold.  I'd suggest trying to just use a high ratio of compression though (like 6 or 8 to 1) and see how that goes.  Hard limiting can have undesirable impacts on the way the voice actually sounds since there are natural dynamics in our speech itself.